# Dynamic buttons that filter objects Django @UPDATE

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

@UPDATE

I want to make dynamic multiple buttons that filtering objects, similar to website https://justjoin.it/brands

For now I've done filtering with **Django-filter** that allows users to filter companies by Type, City and is company open for Students. But this **django-filter** require page to be refreshed which means it's not dynamic updating. It looks like this

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKnJQ.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loiXC.png)

and this is functional, works excellent.

Then I've created simple API with **django-rest-framework** which is accesible on `127.0.0.1:8000/api/companies` and looks like this

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzj6O.png)

and also works fine.

The next thing that I've made is adding jQuery and simple script to get data from API, when someone submit form with `ID=submit` (image below)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zHNX.png)

But now I've stucked because I dont know how to get Data from API and compare this to template. I'm asking for any suggetions because I couldnt find any good example.

My files (updated)

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
import django_filters

TYPES = (
        ('Startup', 'Startup'),
        ('Software House', 'Software House'),
        ....)
CITIES = (
         ('Warszawa', 'Warszawa'),
         ('Poznan', 'Poznan'),
         ....)
COMPANY_TECHNOLOGIES = (
        ('PHP', 'PHP'),
        ('js', 'JavaScript'),
        ....)
STUDENTS = (
        ('No', 'No'),
        ('Yes', 'Yes')
    )
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    students = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=STUDENTS)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=TYPES)
    workers = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    city = models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=CITIES)
    stack = MultiSelectField(choices=COMPANY_TECHNOLOGIES)
    ....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Company
from .filters import CompanyFilter
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import CompanySerializer
# Create your views here.

def companies_list(request):
    my_companies = Company.objects.all()

    ## filter by company type
    type = request.GET.get('type')
    if type:
        my_companies = Company.objects.filter(type=type)
    ## filter by company city
    city = Company.objects.all()
    if city:
        my_companies = Company.objects.filter(city=city)
    ## filter by company technologies
    stack = request.GET.get('stack')
    if stack:
        my_companies = Company.objects.filter(city=city)

    my_companies = my_companies.order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'company/companies_list.html', {'my_companies': my_companies})

def comp_list(request):
    f = CompanyFilter(request.GET, queryset=Company.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'company/comp_list.html', {'filter': f})

##def brands(request, slug):
  ##  brands = Company.objects.all()
    ##return render(request, 'company/comp_view.html', {'brands': brands})

def brands(request, pk):
    brand = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'company/comp_view.html', {'brand': brand})
```

comp_list.html

```
{% extends 'company/base.html' %}
{% block content %}


    <div id="filter">
    <form action="" method="get" id="submit">
        {{ filter.form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    {% for obj in filter.qs %}
    <a href="/brands/{{obj.id}}">{{ obj.name }}</a>
        <p>Image {% if obj.image != None %}
        <img src="{{ obj.image.url }}">
        {% endif%}</p>
        <p>Icon {% if obj.icon != None %}
        <img src="{{ obj.icon.url }}" width="30" height="30">
        {% endif%}</p>

        <br> Type: {{  obj.type }} City: {{ obj.city }} Stack: {{  obj.stack }} 
         <br />
         <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import Company
from rest_framework import serializers

    class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Company
            fields = "__all__"
```

filters.py

```
import django_filters
from .models import Company, COMPANY_TECHNOLOGIES
from django_filters import ChoiceFilter

    class CompanyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

        class Meta:
            model = Company
            fields = ['type', 'city', 'students']

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(CompanyFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.filters['type'].extra.update(
                {'empty_label': 'All'})
            self.filters['city'].extra.update(
                {'empty_label': 'All'})
            self.filters['students'].extra.update(
                {'empty_label': 'All'})
```

ajax.js

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/companies/",
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
        }
        })});
```

Comment: I forgot to add, I'm planning to create single page app that's why I dont want to create any search form etc, I want all search filters as buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering is usually done via GET parameters.

In this example, if you add `?company_name=acme` to the URL, only company names with acme in the name would be shown:

```
def companies_list(request):
    my_companies = company.objects.filter(
        published_date__lte=timezone.now())

    company_name = request.GET.get('company_name', None)
    if company_name:
        my_companies = my_companies.filter(company_name__icontains=company_name)

    my_companies = my_companies.order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'company/index.html', {'my_companies': my_companies})
```

There's also [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to ease this stuff.

As for the SPA, this is beyond the scope of the question, but it should be done with an AJAX request and replacing the DOM element with the response of the view, or returning a JSONResponse and building the element with JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, I've checked django-filter and I think it will helps a lot. About this SPA - yes I know that i will need AJAX requests but I will try to find another simplier way than replacing DOM elements etc. Thank you for help :)

Comment: Hi @phoibos, can u tell me your opinion on 1 thing? I've created filtering with django-filter, now I'm thinking about to create API with django-rest-framework, in this API get in JSON filter values like /search?city=value?type=value?stack=value and then with this JSON generated from API make with jQuery and Ajax buttons, do you think it makes sense?

Comment: Yes, this is quite common. In fact, `django-filter` supports [django rest framwork quite well](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend).

Comment: Hey @phoibos, I've done API with DRF and now I can access this API on localhost/api/companies but now I've stucked, I mean idk whats next. Could you please tell me what should I do first? Add buttons to template or write ajax function?